# Multiplying gradient with matrix in backpropagation in neural networks using tensorflow or pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, neural-network, backpropagation

I want to make the gradient multiplied by a specific matrix in backpropagation using tensorflow or pytorch, how to do that?

I found these lines of code maybe solve the problem but it is written in tensorflow 1.x and I didn't find documentation for it:

```py
feed_dict = { self.r: r, self.input_mask: input_mask, self.output_mask: input_mask }
cost, _ = self.sess.run([self.cost, self.train_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I found this code also:

```py
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.cost)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gvs] 
self.optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs, global_step=self.global_step)
```